# Oracle sequence.NEXTVAL strange order from JSP app

Tags: oracle, jsp, sequence

I am developing a JSP application in JSP with Oracle 11gr2. I have created a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Movie_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 99999 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20;
```

Inserting data from sql developer seems fine: the primary key takes values in order 1,2,3,etc.
But when I try to insert row from JSP calling a function:

```
add_m(Movie_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ....)
```

which executes a statement like

```
insert into table_name values(Movie_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ...)
```

the sequence generates numbers like : 1,2,22,23,30,...not in order. Why??
Could you please explain me what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is because cache size.
Oracle caches count of nextval for fast access of each transaction.

Comment: So, if I want the sequence numbers to be generated in order can I set the cache to 0? Also, I have altered the sequence with _order_.

Comment: Can you try this?
ALTER SEQUENCE zzNOCACHE;

Comment: I've set it using JDveloper's GUI. I will see if that's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle:](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:369390500346406705)

> You cannot expect a sequence to return gap free values. A sequence has one  purpose: assign unique numbers to stuff. Nothing else. There
>   will be gaps, gaps are normal, expected, good, ok, fine. They will be
>   there, there is no avoiding them.